# How to cancel an NSTimer after 60 seconds?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have a button action that sends data to Parse. Once the button is pressed, the title changes to Cancel, when the "Cancel" button is pressed, the data is removed from Parse. I would like to know how to cancel automatically with NSTimer after 60 seconds. I have an array set up too (var isCalling = false)

```
// Function called by within NSTimer in button action

func refresh(){
    self.callButtonTapped(nil)
    !isCalling
}

// Within the button action

   if error == nil {
                        //Success
                        self.isCalling = true
                        self.callButton.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                        self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector (self.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`, just replace this line:

```
self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

with

**Swift 2**

```
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Read [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) if you want to know more about creating timers.